# JavaMail + Outlook: how to write a Unit tests

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I find JavaMail very easy to use. But what about unit tests?

*Can I (with help of javamail) access my outlook accout, find the letter with specific title, and than assert the content?*

*What is the better way to so?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends on your definition of "unit test" and how ambitious you are.

If you're willing to depend on an already-running server with specific content in specific folders, then yes, you can "find the letter with specific title and then assert the content".

If you're more ambitious, you can have the unit test start a "dummy" or "test" server.  The existing JavaMail unit tests in the JavaMail workspace do this.  You can also consider having the unit tests start a "real" mail server.

Comment: I want to run my unit tests on thecorporate server wich is used by my app

Answer (score 1):

For JavaMail unittests you can have 
a look at JavaMail Mock2 https://github.com/salyh/javamail-mock2

Its primarily focused on IMAP/POP3 but SMTP Mock is also available. Its available in maven central.

Features

- Support imap, imaps, pop3, pop3s, smtp, smtps

  Supported for POP3: cast to POP3Folder, Folder.getUID(Message msg)

  Supported for IMAP: cast to IMAPFolder, cast to UIDFolder, Subfolders, -Folder.getMessagesByUID(...), delete/rename folders, append messages

  Support for SMTP: Mock Transport.send()

Unsupported for the moment: IMAP extensions like IDLE, CONDSTORE, ... and casts to POP3Message/IMAPMessage, store listeners